# publish cmd_vel?

Tags: ros, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello guys

how can i publish cmd_vel at for instance 20 times per sec ??  where should this be included ??

```
velPub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/agv1/cmd_vel", 20);
```

this way ??

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    ros::init(argc, argv, "image_processor");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
                                                
    cv::namedWindow("blob");
    cv::createTrackbar("LowerH", "blob", &LowerH, 179, NULL);
    cv::createTrackbar("UpperH", "blob", &UpperH, 179, NULL);
    cv::createTrackbar("LowerS", "blob", &LowerS, 255, NULL);
    cv::createTrackbar("UpperS", "blob", &UpperS, 255, NULL);
    cv::createTrackbar("LowerV", "blob", &LowerV, 255, NULL);
    cv::createTrackbar("UpperV", "blob", &UpperV, 255, NULL);

    //cv::namedWindow(WINDOW, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    //cv::namedWindow(RESULT, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    ros::Subscriber dep;

    dep = nh.subscribe("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1, depthcallback);
    image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/camera/rgb/image_rect_color", 1, blobDetectionCallback);

    followmemsg_pub = nh.advertise<blobdetection::Followmemsg>("/agv1/bt/followmemsg", 10);
    //follow_msg.person == 1;


    ros::ServiceServer service = nh.advertiseService("followmeservice", followmesrv);
    velPub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/agv1/cmd_vel", 20);
    pub = it.advertise("camera/image_processed", 1);
    
    ros::Rate rate(20.0);
    geometry_msgs::Twist speed;

    int count = 1;
    while (nh.ok()) 
    {
        std_msgs::String msg;
        ros::Publisher velPub;
        //std::stringstream ss;
   
        if (hasNewPcl && isStop == true || isStart == true) 
        {
            getXYZ(posX, posY);
            hasNewPcl = false;
        }
        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }
}
```

please help..

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261544/publish-cmd_vel-!!/) by [zubair](https://answers.ros.org/users/29938/zubair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2017-05-11

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publishers only publish when you actually call the `publish` method. Note that in the [C++ Publisher example](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) they enter a while loop that sleeps for 1/10 seconds and then calls the `publish` method. The last argument that you tried to change is [the queue_size](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a6b655c04f32c4c967d49799ff9312ac6).

Here's a slightly modified example from the aforementioned tutorial:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Publisher velPub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/agv1/cmd_vel", 1);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(20);

    geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        msg.linear.x += 0.1;
        velPub.publish(msg);
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zubair](https://answers.ros.org/users/29938/zubair/) on 2017-05-12**:
hi thanks for answering ,, please check the edited part above,, its giving me error, speed is  not declared in this scope, and vel pub is not declared in this scope..  beacsue i am using this in a function in my other part of program,, apart from main

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-05-12**:
You are asking a general C++ question, and this is not the place to do that. I encourage you to learn the basics of C++ before diving into writing ROS nodes. You could also possibly switch to Python which is a bit easier to get started with, IMO.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-05-12**:
Your `velPub` issue is because in the advertise line you don't name a type and you haven't yet declared the  velPub variable. You should probably delete the `ros::Publisher velPub;` line from your while loop and add the `ros::Publisher` before your advertise line, just like in my example.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-05-12**:
I'm guessing the `speed` issue is actually coming from a different function that you didn't post. You must be using that variable in some other function, but never declaring it with a line like `geometry_msgs::Twist speed;`.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-05-12**:
Check out this [variable declaration tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) and this [variable scope tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm) to understand why what you're doing is not okay.